# How can googleMap set OnTouchListener?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, ontouchlistener

How can googleMap set OnTouchListener?
I am trying this code but error:

```
GoogleMap googleMap = …;

googleMap.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            Log.e("MOVE: ","moving");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: and what is the error ?

Comment: Error:(97, 13) error: cannot find symbol method setOnTouchListener(<anonymous OnTouchListener>)

Answer (score 0):

Use [GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener)

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, arg0.latitude + "-" + arg0.longitude);
    }

});
```

EDIT

Use [GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener)

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        LatLng latLng = cameraPosition.target;
        // do your thing with "latLng"
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks. but I want to use touchlistener. because while map is moving I want to do somethings.

Comment: @Ahmet maybe GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener? onCameraChange receives a CameraPosition, who has LatLng field..

Comment: @Ahmet you're welcome. please let me know if it works

Comment: OnCameraChangeListener is now depricated, use mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener () instead.